# Getting value from 1 column base on another

Tags: r

I have 2 df.

df_tailnum, a list of unique tailnum

```
   TailNum
   <chr>  
 1 N657AW 
 2 N834AW 
 3 N605AW 
 4 N312AW 
 5 N309AW 
 6 N733UW 
 7 N177UW 
 8 N404US 
 9 N722UW 
10 N104UW
```

And df_planes, with information on the names of the tailnum

```
  tailnum type   manufacturer  issue_date model status aircraft_type engine_type year 
  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>         <chr>      <chr> <chr>  <chr>         <chr>       <chr>
1 N997AT  Corpo… BOEING        01/02/2003 717-… Valid  Fixed Wing M… Turbo-Fan   2002 
2 N997DL  Corpo… MCDONNELL DO… 03/11/1992 MD-88 Valid  Fixed Wing M… Turbo-Fan   1992 
3 N998AT  Corpo… BOEING        01/23/2003 717-… Valid  Fixed Wing M… Turbo-Fan   2002 
4 N998DL  Corpo… MCDONNELL DO… 04/02/1992 MD-88 Valid  Fixed Wing M… Turbo-Jet   1992 
5 N999CA  Forei… CANADAIR      07/09/2008 CL-6… Valid  Fixed Wing M… Turbo-Jet   1998 
6 N999DN  Corpo… MCDONNELL DO… 04/02/1992 MD-88 Valid  Fixed Wing M… Turbo-Jet   1992
```

I would like to know how do I add value from year column in df_planes to df_tailnum as a new column base on the corresponding tailnum?

something like this:

```
   TailNum Year
   <chr>  
 1 N657AW 
 2 N834AW 
 3 N605AW 
 4 N312AW 
 5 N309AW 
 6 N733UW 
 7 N177UW 
 8 N404US 
 9 N722UW 
10 N104UW
```

I tried

```
df_tailnum <- df_planes %>%
  if_else(df_planes$tailnum == df_tailnum$TailNum,select(df_planes$year))
  mutate()
```

which I realise doesn't make sense.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `if_else` is a vector-based function, not a verb for working on the whole data at once. At best it should be within a `mutate` or `summarize` call, not on its own. (This is breaking partially because of the `%>%` dumping a `data.frame` into its first argument.)
2. (Almost) Never use `df_planes$` within a dplyr pipe.
3. This is an advanced operation known as "merge" or "join". It's a good one to know, but if you're just starting with `data.frame`s and R (and not yet SQL or similar), then it might be a big. See [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272) and [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5706437/3358272) for good discussions on how it works (both in R and in general).

Try these:

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
left_join(df_tailnum, df_planes, by = c(TailNum = "tailnum"))
#    TailNum type manufacturer issue_date model status aircraft_type engine_type year
# 1   N657AW <NA>         <NA>       <NA>  <NA>   <NA>          <NA>        <NA>   NA
# 2   N834AW <NA>         <NA>       <NA>  <NA>   <NA>          <NA>        <NA>   NA
### ...

left_join(df_tailnum, select(df_planes, tailnum, year), by = c(TailNum = "tailnum"))
#    TailNum year
# 1   N657AW   NA
# 2   N834AW   NA
# 3   N605AW   NA
### ...
```

Nothing is found because your sample data has nothing in common between them, but the method is sound.

### base R

```r
merge(df_tailnum, df_planes, by.x = "TailNum", by.y = "tailnum", all.x = TRUE)
```

Comment: thank you!! I'll go look into merge and join operations.